# Call function javascript on html button onclick, passing param ASP

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, node.js

I'm using node, i passed a param like this:

```
res.render('page.ejs',{"product" : product });
```

product is JSON.

In page.ejs
I have to call a javascript function passing product like parameter: `<button onClick='add(<%product%>)' > add </button>`

But,in add function, prodotto is undefined.
How could i do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `<%=product%>` instead of `<%product%>`

see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/976112/introduction-to-asp-net-inline-expressions-in-the-net-framework

HTH!

Comment: <%= gives me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: @afohr can you share the code where you define `product` ?

Comment: i have a list of products, which are passed after a response from a request, i passed this products like this: res.render('page.ejs',{"product" : product });
Then in page.ejs i have a forEach which scans every product.